# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when installing plugin in ktor

Tags: ktor, ktor-client

I am trying to add Resources plugin into my ktor client using the following code:

```
...
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.call.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.java.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.resources.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*
...

...
val HTTP_CLIENT = HttpClient(Java) {
            install(Resources)
        }
...
```

And here's part of my build.gradle.kts:

```
val ktor_version: String by project

plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.6.10"
    kotlin("jvm") version kotlinVersion
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version kotlinVersion
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.2")

    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-java:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-resources:$ktor_version")
}
```

The compile is successful, but when running I got following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void io.ktor.client.HttpClientConfig.install$default(io.ktor.client.HttpClientConfig, io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpClientPlugin, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1, int, java.lang.Object)'
2022-04-16 13:28:45 W/stderr:   at NMEBoot-1.1.mirai.jar//NoMathExpectation.NMEBoot.wolframAlpha.Conversation$Companion$HTTP_CLIENT$1.invoke(Conversation.kt:20)
2022-04-16 13:28:45 W/stderr:   at NMEBoot-1.1.mirai.jar//NoMathExpectation.NMEBoot.wolframAlpha.Conversation$Companion$HTTP_CLIENT$1.invoke(Conversation.kt:19)
2022-04-16 13:28:45 W/stderr:   at io.ktor.client.HttpClientKt.HttpClient(HttpClient.kt:41)
2022-04-16 13:28:45 W/stderr:   at NMEBoot-1.1.mirai.jar//NoMathExpectation.NMEBoot.wolframAlpha.Conversation.<clinit>(Conversation.kt:19)
```

I checked the jar and the source code and they both did have install method, but their signature was different from the signature described in the error.

I don't know if it is my fault or something else. Could someone help me solve this problem?

Edit: Here's a simplified project: [KtorInstallTest](https://github.com/NoMathExpectation/ktorInstallTest)

Comment: It's better to [report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue) such issues directly to the maintainers, including a sample project using which the bug can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/mamoe/mirai/issues/1981) on the Mirai side.

> Mirai Console uses Kotlin 1.6.0 and for some reasons forces all plugins to use the same version of Kotlin, causing this problem. We plan to update to 1.6.20 by Mirai 2.11.0.